# ¿Puedo ocultar src de un video?

Tags: jquery, html5

Estoy desarrollando un panel de infoproductos que se reproducirán videos, quiero evitar la descarga de los videos, ¿Comó puedo hacerlo?

Uso Html5

```
  <video class="dimvideo" controls><source src="videos/CompresoSE.mp4" type="video/mp4">                                                                  
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

Pero a lo mejor que se vea asi

```
       <video class="dimvideo" controls>
        <source src="56456456/5645gfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg" type="video/mp4">                           
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
         </video>
```

Se puede bloquear el descargar los videos? asi como creo que lo hace Lynda.com

La src de sus videos es asi 
               http://files2.lynda.com/secure/courses/486757/VBR_MP4h264_main_SD/486757_00_01_WX30_Welcome.mp4?c3.ri=3774722125160034211&hashval=1478303759_ada29ab4bbab2aab1047b2ddb017557c

Ingresas al enlace y te sale algo asi.

```
 An error occurred while processing your request.
 Reference #50.47d63fc8.1478289421.5950864
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que la gente no pueda ver el link desde dónde se está reproduciendo el video? Es que por la pregunta puedo entender una cosa, pero por el contenido otra distinta.

Comment: **no puedes**... todo lo que se sirve al cliente se puede descargar

Comment: Si, exacto @Error404 deseo ocular el src del video para evitar que se pueda descargar de alguna manera.!

Comment: PUEDES MOSTRAR TU URL

Comment: Voy recién a desarrollarlo @m3w y quería tener información extra.

Comment: Prueba enmascarando la url de tu video con blob:

Comment: Utilizas alguna tecnologia backend como java en tu servicio?

Comment: Usa Base64 para cubrir la url.

Comment: Vor a buscar documentación al respecto.

Comment: Con este tutorial va hasta ahora bien la codificacion https://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri

Answer (score 1):

haz que tu src no apunte a un archivo físico, si no mas bien a un handler o controllers con un metodo que responda a peticiones get. Este lee la petición del video(puede ser el nombre real o encriptado) MAS un token para ese video valido creado por ti(eso lo defines tu... lo mas básico sería un token o ticket maestro para esa petición del video)  puedes además agregar el checkeo de alguna cookie o token de autentificacion o cookie que exista sólo cuando se hagan peticiones desde tu página... no se eso queda a tu imaginación(puedes también hacer que expire el token para ese video(lo mejor es que el token sea para un video y usuario actual así con trolas que no se compartan el enlace... se me ocurren mil formas más pero esas básicamente )
entonces finalmente en tu controllers tienes un método que sea /video(id,tokevalidoentregadoportuappParaEseVideoyEseUsuario,otros...) dentro lees más datos de autentificacion (cookie token etc si tu sistema usa alguno claro está ) y finalmente respondes con un Stream que lee el archivo físico dentro del server. Este método puede ser un void que escribe el response válido para que el reproductor obtenga el video.

Answer (score 0):

para no mostrar una url que termina .pdf .mp4 puedes utilizar la libreria restful que ocultara tu url por ejemplo era asi mipagina/videos/xmen.mp4 y con restful sera mipagina/videos

Comment: De todos modos la persona puede ver el vídeo si va a las herramientas de desarrollador y mira los recursos.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro claro pero no todos son desarrolladores, no todos saben ir a las herramientas de desarrollador

Comment: @rn3w - pero luego habrá desarrolladores que crean una herramienta para la gente *normales*...listo para descargar

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es posible, ya que cuando la imagen(o video) carga en el navegador del usuario, este, ya "descargo" esa imagen(o video) desde alguna fuente para asi mostrarla. En el caso de las imagenes para el usuario seria tan facil como

Click derecho :

- Guardar imagen como...
- Copiar URL imagen...